# How to redirect automatically php js

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

How can I redirect automatically

when visitor come check if mousemove or keypress or mouseclick or scrolling & redirect to $activitly if not send they to other url

checking methods:

1. mousemove
2. mouseclick
3. key press
4. scrolling

start checking time when page reload ..redircet checking time is 15 scnds
this is code

```
$aff_array = array("http://www.google.COM",
                  "http://google.fr",
                  "http://google.es");
$random = rand(0, count($aff_array) - 1);
$activitly  = $aff_array[$random];

?>
<!-- HTML code -->
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title></title>

<script language="JavaScript">
function set_interval() {
  //the interval 'timer' is set as soon as the page loads  
  var timeoutMins = 1000 * 1 * 15; // 15 seconds
  var timeout1Mins = 1000 * 1 * 13; // 13 seconds
  itimer=setInterval("auto_logout()",timeoutMins);

}

function reset_interval() {
  var timeoutMins = 1000 * 1 * 5; // 15 seconds 
  var timeout1Mins = 1000 * 1 * 3; // 13 seconds
  //resets the timer. The timer is reset on each of the below events:
  // 1. mousemove   2. mouseclick   3. key press 4. scrolling
  //first step: clear the existing timer
  clearInterval(itimer);
  clearInterval(atimer);
  //second step: implement the timer again
  itimer=setInterval("auto_logout()",timeoutMins);
}


function auto_logout() {
  //this function will redirect the user to the logout script
  window.open('self.location', '_self');
}
</script>

</head>
<body onLoad="set_interval(); document.form1.exp_dat.focus();" onKeyPress="reset_interval();" onmousemove="reset_interval();" onclick="reset_interval();" onscroll="reset_interval();">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$inactivitly  = header("Location: safe.com");` - That's not how to use `header()`. When you use `header()`, the header will be sent to the client. It won't return anything you can store in a variable.

Comment: You should also explain what your current issues with your code are. What suppose to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i will iexplain now i need code to check if visitor mouse move or not if move i will redirect to url if not iwill redirect to other url

Comment: CHECK TIME IS ON 15 SCOUNDS

Comment: Why are you screaming? You still haven't told is what _happens_ when you run your code. If you just want to know how to detect a mouse move and how to set a timeout in js, you should have been able to find it easily using google.

Comment: Btw, `1000 * 1 * 5` isn't 15 sec. It's 5 sec and `1000 * 1 * 3` is 3 sec, not 13.

Comment: WHY DO YOU KEEP SCREAMING? Writing in all caps equals screaming. It's not nice to scream at people. _"this all when I run my code"_ - This all what? Since you keep screaming and don't seem to want to explain your issue _properly_, I'm out...

Comment: when visitor come check if mousemove or keypress or mouseclick   or scrolling redirect to $activitly
if not send they to other url

Comment: @MagnusEriksson plz rply W
when visitor come check if mousemove or keypress or mouseclick or scrolling redirect to $activitly if not send they to other url